# Как разделить строку по определенному символу в ней

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re, строки

Есть огромный текст в котором много строк разделенных \n и нужно этот текст разделить на сообщения по 4096 символов или меньше по последнему символу \n.
Пока выходит делить только по числу символов, не знаю как двигаться дальше

```
match = re.match(r'[\w\W]{4096}', text)
```

Comment: Приведите пример. Сейчас ваше описание можно понимать разными способами. Приведите в пример текст с несколькими переводами строки - и что вы хотели бы видеть на выходе. Для примера можете ограничение поставить скажем 20 символов вместо 4096. И лучше приведите несколько таких примеров.

Comment: Может, `re.findall(r'.{1,4096}\n', text, re.S)`?